# How to check if an element is in a list

Tags: python, list

Im trying to code a function which takes as input a list representing a sparse ruler of reach N and returns True if it is complete and False otherwise. A sparse ruler is:A sparse ruler of reach N is complete if it is possible to measure all distances between 1 and N by taking the differences between two marks. So far I have:

```
def ismyrulercomplete(myruler):
    iscomplete= True
    for i in myruler:
        if myruler[i] != [abs(i-j)for i in myruler for j in myruler if i != j]:
            iscomplete = False
            return iscomplete
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if an element is in a list using the `in` operator.

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
print( (7 in A) )
print( (6 in A) )
```

Output:

```
>> False
>> True
```

Also, the indent level of your `return` statement should be the same as your `iscomplete= True` line.